# random crashes with pointers and recursion

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, assimp

Im trying to map bones using recursive function. My goal is to run IterateBones on root bone to insert pointers to vector of pointers to Bones structure and every other children of children;

```
struct Bone
{
    int Id;
    std::vector<Bone*> BoneChild;
};
```

```
void IterateBones(aiNode* t,Bone* b,std::vector<Bone>& Bones, std::map<std::string,Bone*> Map)
{
        for(int g = 0 ; g<t->mNumChildren;g++)
        {
            Bone* Bon = Map.find(t->mChildren[g]->mName.data)->second;
            b->BoneChild.push_back(&Bones[Bon->Id]);
            IterateBones(t->mChildren[g],Bon,Bones,Map);
        }
    return;
}
```

aiNode* t is assimp pointer to node of bone,

Bone* b is pointer of currently iterated bone

std::vector& Bones is reference to vector of bones inside other class

std:: Map is mapped pointers to Bone structures by names in Bones vector

My problem is that the code works flawlessely 75% times, but 25% times the program crashes. i tried to debug with DBG, but it gave me segfault once, and other times it runs without any errors.
Could anyone explain why is it happening and how i could prevent this, because i have simillar piece of code but it crashes most times

im using GC++ with mingw-w64

Comment: My initial comment is that `BoneChild` is a metal variable name.

Comment: Taking a wild guess, I would say the problem is that you are storing pointers to vector elements but if the vector gets resized then that pointer (potentially) becomes invalid. Seems to fit, you are storing pointers, you are resizing vectors and your bug is intermittent.

Comment: the Bones vector doesnt gets updated or modified after the IterateBones

Comment: Maybe not, but it's the pointers stored during IterateBones I'm worried about.

Comment: Here's a test, before you call IterateBones reserve a large amount of memory for your vector (more than you could possibly need), if the bug goes away, then pointer invalidation was the problem.

Comment: b->BoneChild.reserve(500); adding this doesnt remove the bug but changing the BoneChild to normal pointer fixes it

Comment: How about `Bones.reserve(500);` ?

Comment: @aa112233 *My problem is that the code works flawlessely 75% times* -- There is no such thing as working flawlessly 75% of the time.  Flawless means it works 100% of the time.

Comment: adding Bones.reserve(500) fixed it, it would mean that pointers in Map are invaild and causing the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by @john and @EMarci15 in comments, it required to reserve Bones Vector

```
Bones.reserve(500)
```

Comment: Just as a side-note: this likely doesn't *really* fix your bug, merely hides it. The real problem is that you are adding elements to `Bones` after storing pointers to its elements. It would probably be valuable to find and eliminate that. (Otherwise the crash may return once you have, say, 501 bones.)

Comment: i know, i will fetch amount of bones and the Bones vector reserve will be based on that